# Android ant get copied files path

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I'm trying to copy modified files from eclipse Package Explorer to my local machine using ant and during copy i want to make list of all the copied files in the .txt file with the absolute path.

```
      <copy todir="F:\PartnerFolders\Exammodify" verbose="yes" failonerror="false"> 

         <fileset dir="C:\Users\nik\workspace\Exam\src">
          <modified update="true"
                    seldirs="true"
                    cache="propertyfile"
                    algorithm="digest"
                    comparator="equal">
                <param name="cache.cachefile" value="cache.properties"/>
                <param name="algorithm.algorithm" value="MD5"/>
            </modified>
          </fileset>             

    </copy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your fileset into `<path id=".."> ... </path>`, and use [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) and [echo](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html) to print it to file, f.e. :

```
<copy todir="F:\PartnerFolders\Exammodify" verbose="yes" failonerror="false"> 
 <path id="foobar">
  <fileset dir="C:\Users\nik\workspace\Exam\src">
   <modified update="true" seldirs="true" cache="propertyfile" algorithm="digest" comparator="equal">
    <param name="cache.cachefile" value="cache.properties" />
    <param name="algorithm.algorithm" value="MD5" />
   </modified>
  </fileset>
 </path>
</copy>

 <!-- use linefeed as separator -->
 <pathconvert refid="foobar" property="foo" pathsep="${line.separator}" />

 <!-- echoing to stdout .. -->
 <echo>${foo}</echo>

 <!-- .. or some file -->
 <echo file="C:/whatever/log.txt">${foo}</echo>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried your code it will create log.txt file but the file is blank and it echoing nothing.

Comment: @Nik The snippet should work as expected. When file is blank it means that fileset is empty. What is your ant version ?

Comment: My ant version is 1.8.3

Comment: @Nik It should definitely work, use a simple fileset to see if it works for you. If your fileset is empty the file will be empty too, so you need to check the fileset definition.